# Restart a process [exe] in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a C++ exe; under a particular scenario I need to stop the exe and start it up again. This has to be done from within the same exe and not from outside. What is the best way to achieve this?

My guess is to start a new instance of the process and then kill the running process. But is there any straight forward API to do this, like RestartProcess() or something? If not what do you suggest?

Comment: hey rusty, just out of interest, why did you make this a community wiki?

Comment: It would be a good idea for you to explain why you think you need to do this - there may be a better and easier solution.

Comment: @Neil: Don't know about rusty, but I've sometimes implemented very much the same thing in order to support upgrading running software automatically, without any user intervention: the program renames the current app.exe to app_old.exe, then downloads the new .exe and writes it to disk as app.exe, then calls CreateProcess(). On failure, the still-running old version deletes new app.exe, renames app_old.exe to app.exe, and logs the error. On apparent success, it just closes itself. But if you have a better solution, please tell us!  (I did it very much like sharptooth explains => +1 to him. :)

Comment: (I understand that this approach may sound somewhat abusive, and actually I felt the same way when writing the implementation... But in the end, it worked very well.)

Comment: ok the reason is a trigger from external hardware. the process has to be restarted in such a case.

Comment: and the reason for community wiki; well am a newbie here. shouldn't have done it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no such built-in method. You really have to detect the path to the executable (GetCurrentModule(), then GetModuleFileName()), run the new process (CreateProcess()), then exit the current process (ExitProcess()).

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard [exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w.aspx) function. it runs a program and does not return, in effect replacing the current running program with a new one.